# SQL Alchemy Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables but foreign keys are specified

Tags: sqlalchemy

I got table that reference twice to another table, but got AmbiguousForeignKeysError. I specified foreign keys, but have no luck.

My simplified models are:

```
    class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    manager_of = relationship("Project", back_populates="manager")
    teamlead_of = relationship("Project", back_populates="teamlead")

class Project(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    manager_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    manager = relationship(
        "User", back_populates="manager_of", foreign_keys=[manager_id], uselist=False
    )

    teamlead_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    teamlead = relationship(
        "User", back_populates="teamlead_of", foreign_keys=[teamlead_id], uselist=False
    )
```

Error that I got:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.manager_of - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

What am i doing wrong?